# Running commands with django-extensions

Tags: python, django, command, django-extensions

I have intalled [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) in my django project, and I would like to use the *reset_db* command.

However, I can't access any of the extended commands.
When running `./manage.py help` , I only see the commands associated with django, nothing from django-extensions.

I don't really know what I am doing wrong... Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the app to the installed apps list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I was sure I had already added it, since I am using some models from it, but you are right, it wasn't there. Thanks a lot.